# get dollars from cents using moneyphp

Tags: laravel, money-php

How can I use [moneyphp/money](https://github.com/moneyphp/money) to get the money in dollars from cents?

I am storing `price` as cents in my database, and lets say I have this accessor in a laravel model

```php
    public function getPriceAttribute($price)
    {
        $fiver = Money::USD(1425);
        dd($fiver->getAmount());
    }
```

the `getAmount` method will show `1425` while I am expecting `14.25`

Comment: Why not just divide your result by 100?

Comment: I want to use this package for other logic in getPriceAttribute

Comment: well, you could adjust the function with conditions, and use it anywhere it fits..

Answer (score 2):

MoneyPHP internally stores the amount in cents as a string. The `getAmount` method simply returns the internally stored amount.

To get a formatted amount from MoneyPHP you should use a [formatter](https://moneyphp.org/en/stable/features/formatting.html#intl-decimal-formatter).

```
<?php
use Money\Currencies\ISOCurrencies;
use Money\Currency;
use Money\Formatter\IntlMoneyFormatter;
use Money\Money;

$money = new Money(1425, new Currency('USD'));
$currencies = new ISOCurrencies();

$numberFormatter = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$moneyFormatter = new IntlMoneyFormatter($numberFormatter, $currencies);

echo $moneyFormatter->format($money); // outputs 14.25
```

If you also need the currency symbol replace `NumberFormatter::DECIMAL` with `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY`.